# catalogProductAttributeMediaRemove does not remove Image from the disk in Magento 1.9 CE

Tags: magento, soap

We update product photos via SOAP sequence:

```
catalogProductAttributeMediaList
catalogProductAttributeMediaRemove
catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate
```

By calling SOAP catalogProductAttributeMediaRemove Magento does not remove photos from the disk/db .

The deleted photo still can be accessible by url for example: www.example.com/media/catalog/product/P/A/PAexample.jpg

Also after calling catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate the photo name is changed automatically by Magento to PAexample_1.jpg and then PAexample_2.jpg ..... in subsequent photo updates (SOAP sequence).

And we can not have the same file name after product photo updates.

Wondering what could be best work around?